# Combining string and aggregate function within bar chart label in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I have made two interactive linked histograms with crossfiltering using Altair. I have created labels over each bar with the sum of the filtered items by using mark_text(). Below is an image of the linked charts:

[image]

I would like learn how to concatenate a string in the label so that it would look something like: 'error: 481.1'. This is the relevant code snippet:

```
crossfilter = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])

tick_up = alt.Chart().transform_filter(crossfilter).mark_tick(color='black').encode(
                                x = x, 
                                y = alt.Y(plus_error+':Q', aggregate='sum'))
text = tick_up.mark_text(
        align='left',
        baseline='middle',
        dx=12  
    ).encode(text='sum(error):Q')
```

When I try to change `.encode(text='sum(error):Q')` to something like `.encode(text='"error": sum(error):Q')`, it throws me an error, is there a simple way to do this? I have also tried using `transform_calculate`, but I need something adapts to what is being selected by `crossfilter`.

I would also like to learn how to create a label with multiple lines, for example:

```
curr_error: 123.1 
previous_error: 110
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `+` in `transform_calculate` to concatenate a string and a number. I believe you will also need `transform_joinaggregate` to have your sum accessible in the calculation transformation. Something like this:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_text(align='left', dx=2).encode(
    x='sum(Horsepower)',
    y='Origin',
    text='label:N'
).transform_joinaggregate(
    sum_hp = 'sum(Horsepower)',
    groupby=['Origin']
).transform_calculate(
    label = "'error: ' + datum.sum_hp"
)

chart.mark_bar() + chart
```

[image]

This also works with a selection, but make sure the `transform_filter` is before the other transforms so that only the selected data points are used for the calculations:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()
brush = alt.selection_interval()

scatter = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Weight_in_lbs',
    color='Origin'
).add_selection(
    brush
)

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_text(align='left', dx=2).encode(
    x='sum(Horsepower)',
    y='Origin',
    text='label:N'
).transform_filter(
    brush
).transform_joinaggregate(
    sum_hp = 'sum(Horsepower)',
    groupby=['Origin']
).transform_calculate(
    label = "'error: ' + datum.sum_hp"
)

scatter & bars.mark_bar() + bars
```

[image]

Comment: hi! thanks for the quick response. I have tried `transform.joinaggregate`, but it seems like it performs the aggregation over the entire dataset. For my use case, I need aggregation to be performed only in filtered entries selected by `alt.selection` (the brushed interval). Does that make sense?

Comment: @meijiu This also works with a selection, but make sure the `transform_filter` is before the other transforms so that only the selected data points are used for the calculations. I added an example.

Comment: yeah, it does work! I just forgot to add the `group_by` argument. Altair is more powerful and extensible than I realized. Do you have any idea how to add link breaks to the labels?

Comment: Yup Altair/VegaLite is pretty cool! Your line break question has an answer here already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64766369/vega-lite-line-break-or-word-wrap-for-labels-in-axis

Comment: I see, thanks :).