# Altair: add numbers of observation per group

Tags: altair

How can I add the numbers of observations per group to a boxplot with altair?

I am looking for something like this:

[image]

But I am also open to other solutions (as long as the information is visible).

For instance, how would I add this information to the example plot from [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/boxplot.html)?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.population.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot(extent='min-max').encode(
    x='age:O',
    y='people:Q'
)
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically modify titles in Altair/Vega-Lite, so you would need to add a text mark with this information. Something like this (just a proof of principal, you would likely add some explanatory text and make it prettier):

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.population.url

boxes = alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot(extent='min-max').encode(
    x='age:O',
    y='people:Q'
)

boxes + boxes.mark_text().encode(
    y=alt.datum(11_500_000),
    text='count()'
)
```

[image]

Two other options are to make the sizes of the boxes correspond to the count or add it as the tooltip.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I add something like `N=...` in front of the text? I tried to use an f-string for the text parameter, but my attempts break the output: `text=f"N={...}"`. I would like to avoid setting tooltips for the boxplot because this would overwrite the existing boxplot standard tooltips.

Comment: @Revan You can see an example here of how to include custom text in transforms https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013335/2166823